# Installation and Update of monero cli and gui

Tags: update

I tried out monero cli and gui and created two wallets with each version, named Walletcli and Walletgui. There is now a Walletcli file in the program directory but no Walletgui file, where is it? Which files are created by the program on which location (Windows)? Where ist the blockchain?
How can I update the program, just copying the new files over the old?
Unfortunately there is no instruction or setup.

Answer (score 1):

> but no Walletgui file, where is it?

Looking for "Monero Wallets" folder on your disk

> Which files are created by the program on which location (Windows)? Where ist the blockchain?

On Windows the blockchain is stored in C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb. It's a hidden folder.

> How can I update the program, just copying the new files over the old?

Yes, you should make a back up if things gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, it seems to be tricky to change between wallets in the GUI. I put all files of the wallets away from the program directory to a seperate wallet directory (that should be essential!). I guess that these 3 files are everything you need: walletname, walletname.adress.txt, walletname.keys?
The GUI starts with one of the wallets and I have to choose Settings - Close_wallet - Choose_language - open_a_wallet_from_file to open the other wallet. A little bit complicated, but it works.

Comment: If your answer best answers your question, then please mark it as the best answer.